# How to use gnome-keyring in lxc ubuntu container?

Tags: lxc, lxd, gnome-keyring, container

I have tried to start the installed `gnome-keyring` in a lxc Ubuntu 16.04 container by executing `sudo gnome-keyring-daemon --start`. However, I got the following errors.

```
** (gnome-keyring-daemon:21983): WARNING **: couldn't create socket directory: /home/ubuntu/.cache/keyring-UPBO6Y: Permission denied

** (gnome-keyring-daemon:21983): WARNING **: couldn't bind to control socket: /home/ubuntu/.cache/keyring-UPBO6Y/control: Permission denied
```

And, the git doesn't seem to be able to use it showing message `** (process:21971): CRITICAL **: Error communicating with gnome-keyring-daemon`.

Thanks

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107785: "It appears on recent systems the gnome-keyring sockets moved form a random directory in ~/.cache/ to /run/user/<ID>/keyring/ (at least on Debian Jessie), so a simple restart should be sufficient."